# How do I change the default start template in CLion?

Tags: c++, clion

I'm trying to change the template that CLion uses at the creation of every c++ project in the main. As of now it reads,

```
#include<iostream>
//I want "using namespace std;" to be here

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I would prefer it to just use the standard namespace instead of putting std:: before cout and endl.
I know its not that big of a deal but it does get annoying to change it every time I open a new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that for now ([feature request in tracker to follow](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5089)). However, such using was removed on [purpose](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6943).